# filehelps importing datetime

Tags: datetime, csv, filehelpers

I'm trying to use the FileHelps to import a csv.  I need the date to be in mmddyyyy format when importing but the defualt is ddmmyyyy.  I see where in c# you use

```
[FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "MMddyyyy" )] 
Public Property BeginningDate as datetime
```

however that doesn't work in vb.net and the converters i've tried aren't helping either.  Was hoping someone could tell me how to covert that.
thanks
shannon

Answer (score 1):

found the answer.

```
 <FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "MMddyyyy")> _
    Public mBeginningDate As DateTime

    Public Property BeginningDate As DateTime
        Get
            Return mBeginningDate
        End Get
        Set(pValue As DateTime)
            mBeginningDate = pValue
        End Set
    End Property
```

Thanks
Shannon